# Urban Airship integration for Flutter project?

Tags: flutter, urbanairship.com

Our team is just getting started comparing Xamarin and Flutter.  On the outset, Flutter seems newer (less battle-hardened) but far sexier for details like [hot-reloading and dual native output](https://youtu.be/prlK_QL_qOA?t=1144).  On the battle-hardened front, however, Xamarin integration with Urban Airship is [well-documented](https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/xamarin/).  This is a sticking point for our project as Urban Airship is a requirement and we're consequently leaning toward Xamarin.

But to give Flutter a fair shake, I thought I'd ask: *How does one integrate Urban Airship into a Flutter project*?  (Obviously would need to work with both Android and iOS.)

My google-fu thus far is not promising.

Comment: https://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua/ seems to be simple REST. You can do that in Dart directly without plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter's solution to interacting with native, platform-specific libraries is [plugins](https://flutter.io/developing-packages/). This is a reusable package of mostly Dart code, some swift or objC code, some java or kotlin code, a sample/test flutter app and some unit tests. The Dart code defines a common interface, with the other language code providing the bindings to the respective platforms, and in your case, vendor provided libraries. The IDE will create you a complete working template of a plugin, and there are plenty of examples to get ideas from in pub.

You use xcode when implementing the ios native code, and android studio (or IDEA) when implementing the android specific code. Luckily, as you are just writing a few bindings, the native code is normally rather thin.

Normally Dart code is calling native methods, but the opposite also works. Native code can also generate events. Flutter takes care of converting Dart parameter and return values to/from native values, and supports simple types, Lists, Maps, etc.

Someone on your team familiar with the vendor library on both platforms should be able to define the common Dart api (the subset of features you use) and implement the native bindings. The plugin handles the rest.